# How to make Selenium repeat a command in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, automation, webautomation

I've just started learning web automation and i can't find a way to repeat a command in an already open browser

here's my code

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get('https://web.whatsapp.com/')

searchchat = driver.find_element_by_xpath('xpath')
searchchat.send_keys('name of group in chat')

chatbutton = driver.find_element_by_xpath('xpath')
chatbutton.click()

typebox = driver.find_element_by_xpath('xpath')
typebox.send_keys('Test')

pressbox = driver.find_element_by_xpath('xpath')
pressbox.click()
```

this just opens up a new instance and creates a heap of other nuisances..

Comment: What do you mean by "opens up a new instance"?  Does it open a new browser tab?

Comment: Opens a new window

Answer (score 0):

Everytime you run your script, it will start a new webdriver instance. So you can not reuse an already open browser.

Comment: Yes that's the point of the question, how do i do it so it won't ?

Comment: The answer is NO. You can not reuse an already open browser.